# Windows 10 RTools cannot connect to Windows Server R Services

Tags: r, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools, rtvs

I have VS2015 with RTools and RTVS on a windows 10 machine.
I also have a Server 2012 with SQL Server, with R Server, and RTVS R Services installed.

I cannot connect the Win-10 RTVS to the RServer using Remote connections.  I have done the following things:

On the Server:

1. Installed the Certificate
2. Installed R Services.  Found both Services `R Host Broker Service` and `R User Profile Service` alive and running.  The associated json is also set.
3. Found both programs listed on the Windows Firewall for allowed on inbound and outbound connections
4. Ensured .net 4.6.1 is set

On the Client Workstation:

1. Installed R Tools for Visual Studio on top of Visual Studio 15 (SSDT)
2. Installed Microsoft R and other related programs.
3. Copied and added the certificate from the server to the workstation's list of trusted certificates.
4. Ensured .net 4.6.1 is set
5. Added Server to Workstation's list of remote workspaces in VS.  Called the workspace 'simulator'

I can telnet to rserver.domain.com with port 5444 to ensure port is listening.

however, when I go to connect to the remote workspace I get this error:

```
Connecting to R Workspace failed.
Reason: Machine 'Simulator' appears to be online, but the Remote R Service is not running.
>
```

I'm missing something, and don't know what.  Where do I go from here?
Thanks.